# How an action call works in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, action

I have the following action method:

```
class CommandsController < ApplicationController
.
.
.
  def usersList
    @command = Command.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @users_list = @command.user_commands.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
  end
end
```

The following view: users_list.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Command list") %>
<h1>Lista Utenti per <%= @command.content %></h1>

<%= will_paginate @users_list %>

<ul class="users">
   <% @users_list.each do |user| %>

   <li><%= user.name.capitalize %>, <%= user.email %></li>

<% end %>
</ul>
```

And in the routes.rb

```
  get 'commands/:id/usersList' => 'commands#users_list', as: :list
```

Now I don't understand why going to lochalhost:3000/commands/1/usersList I receive the following error:

```
undefined method `content' for nil:NilClass
```

refered to line `<h1>Lista Utenti per <%= @command.content %></h1>`
Why does it do so? When I call an action, before it renders the page and then after it executes the code inside the method?

I resolved the problem by changing the names: `usersList --> userslist` and then `users_list.html.erb --->userslist.html.erb` and in the routes.rb ----> `get 'commands/:id/userslist' => 'commands#userslist', as: :list`
Then I don't understand the naming convention...if I declare an action usersList how should I rename the related view?

Comment: Are you sure `Command.find_by(id: params[:id])` actually returns something? What happens if you execute it in the console?

Comment: I executed it in the console and all just runs fine, it retrieves me the related command object

Comment: I resolved the problem by changing the names:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your action name to `users_list`.